# Does restoring an iPhone from backup remove existing data from the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, backup

I want to restore an old backup onto my iPhone. Will that delete the data currently on my iPhone, or does my data get added to what’s in the backup?

Answer (score 5):

Restoring an iPhone from backup will wipe all its contents, then replace everything with what’s in the backup.

Whatever data is on your iPhone now, but not in the backup, will be **GONE** after the restoration process.

Comment: GONE needs more emphasis... :)

Comment: So the data in my Iphone will be deleted after restoration process ?

Comment: Yes, it will be deleted, and replaced by the backup.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you can’t restore a device until you erase the iPhone so the restore doesn’t really erase anything - just that you have to pass through erase to get to restore in the first place.

So I realize my argument is close to "splitting hairs", but I'd say: **Restoring a backup implies everything is erased from the phone - you can’t mix a current set of data with a restore**

Answer (score -1):

When you restore your iPhone, whether it's from backup or as a "new" iPhone, all data on the phone since the last backup that was created will be erased (gone).

If you want to restore your iPhone from backup, the best thing to do is take a backup first using either iCloud backup or through iTunes, then perform the restore process.

Once the phone goes through the setup screen, you can restore from backup or start fresh.

Answer (score -1):

When you recover your iPhone data by using iTunes backups, your current iPhone data will be synced with iTunes backup files. In order words, you can't simply add specific files onto iPhone with iTunes.

Answer (score -2):

I just did a restore and the data saved in the file sharing section of the applications was not removed so the accepted answer is wrong. It might have deleted the data if the app didn't exist before but I didn't try. The software version was not changed. As far as I can tell it just reset a bunch of settings.

Comment: Don't know why correct information was downvoted. I'll do the backup and restore again just to make sure as I've never needed to use it but I don't think I'm mistaken.

Comment: I think it was supposed to be a comment reply to the answer you're talking about